# How to use enums in Interfaces?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, interface, multi-tier

So we have `Order` which is Logic and `IOrderData` which connects the View and the Logic when it comes to data like properties. `Order` has properties of enums `PayMethod` and `OrderStatus`. How do I make properties of `PayMethod` and `OrderStatus` in `IOrderData` without the interface-layer knowing either Logic nor View?

Example:

Project Logic:

```
public class Order : IOrder, IOrderData
{
    public enum PayMethod
    {
        iDeal,
        creditcard,
        PayPal
    }

    public enum OrderStatus
    {
        NotPaid,
        InTheMaking,
        Shipped,
        Delivered,
        Confirmed
    }

public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
public PayMethod Paymethod { get; set; }
```

Project DataInterface:

```
public interface IOrderData
{
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; } //doesn't work
    public PayMethod Paymethod { get; set; } //doesn't work
}
```

My solution: I just made a new Class Library for `Enums` with classes of `PayMethod` and `OrderStatus` and everywhere where enums we're used I referred to the Class Library.

Answer (score 3):

This code doesn't compile because your enums are members of the `Order` class.
If you move them outside the class and make them top-level members of your namespace, as stated in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum):

> Usually it is best to define an `enum` directly within a namespace so that all classes in the namespace can access it with equal convenience. However, an `enum` can also be nested within a class or struct.

This will solve the problem:

```
public enum PayMethod
{
    iDeal,
    creditcard,
    PayPal
}

public enum OrderStatus
{
    NotPaid,
    InTheMaking,
    Shipped,
    Delivered,
    Confirmed
}
```

```
public interface IOrderData
{
    OrderStatus Status { get; set; } 
    PayMethod Paymethod { get; set; }
}
public class Order : IOrder, IOrderData
{

public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
public PayMethod Paymethod { get; set; }
```

Comment: top-level members of my namespace. So does that mean putting it above the namespace or make a whole new project dedicated to enums?

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai If the enums are part of the interface, generally you would put their definitions in the same source code file as the interface itself.

Comment: This means to put them directly under the namespace, not inside the class as the code in the question. You don't need a different project to put them into.

Comment: But the interface can't know the Logic(where the enum is) so it still gives the error

Comment: Enums are not logic. they are merely a group of constants. The interface isn't logic either, it's merely a contract. All the logic is on the type that implements the interface.

Comment: So if I don't put it in the logic namespace, where do I put them than? Because the type still coudn't be found.

Comment: The enums and interfaces belong on the same project. The implementation can be on a different project (I think I've finally understood what it is you're asking here).

Answer (score 1):

Your enums are subtypes to `Order` therefore you have to fully qualify the name with `Order.` like so:

```
public interface IOrderData
{
    Order.OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
    Order.PayMethod Paymethod { get; set; }
}
```

Also `public` doesn't work for interface-members in C# 7.3 and below (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972582/public-interface-member-in-c8) for C# 8+).

Alternatively, you can move the enums outside of the `Order` class like described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027751/10883465).

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of the enums **outside** of the class declaration, otherwise the interface won't know anything about that enum.

```
public enum PayMethod
{
    iDeal,
    creditcard,
    PayPal
}

public enum OrderStatus
{
    NotPaid,
    InTheMaking,
    Shipped,
    Delivered,
    Confirmed
}

public class Order : IOrderData
{
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
    public PayMethod Paymethod { get; set; }
}

public interface IOrderData
{
    OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
    PayMethod Paymethod { get; set; }
}
```